# Probability 4 sets of twins in group 100 people

Tags: probability, combinations

Assume that out of every 200 pregnancies there is one set of twins. This means P1 = 1/200 where P1 is the probability a pregnancy yields twins .  It can be shown that the probability an individual selected at random is not a twin is equal to (1-P1)/(1 + P1) = 199/201 .

If there is a group of N = 100 students in a class what is the probability
there are no pairs of twins? There can be individual people who are twins but their counterpart is not in the group of 100.
My first try is to say this is (199/201)^100  = 0.368.
But not sure how to account for pairs and individuals

Also What is the probability there are 4 sets of twins?  How about N sets of twins ( clearly in this case Nmax is 50. ). Also what is the expected number of sets of twins ?? Need help..

Maybe related to birthday problem ??

Comment: I suspect that the problem is poorly worded, and that your interpretation accurately focuses on the problem.  That is, if you are given that all twin pairs live in the same *region*, then the question becomes affected by how many people live in this region.  I suspect that the problem composer's intent was to mirror the birthday problem, by asking for the probability that out of $N$ people, each person is not part of any twin pair, regardless of whether the other member of the twin pair is part of the N people.

Comment: Not uncommon for poorly worded problems to leave the problem solver *twisting in the wind*.

Comment: I don't get the $(1+P_1)$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of 1 person to have a twin-brother is $\frac{2}{200} = 1$%

Your question is to calculate the probability of having N sets of twin in 100
students, this is not relate to the probability of N people have-a-twin-brother.

Imagine each people wear bags with unique color and twins have the same color of bag, you can't tell the probability of having the same bag in class because you don't know how many color there are.

This problem need to be fixed or give more detail information.